# Why isn't the action bar text color changing?

Tags: android, android-appcompat

I am on android lollipop and using the following style as my theme `MyNavigationDrawerTheme`

in styles v14

```
<style name="MyNavigationDrawerTheme" parent="MaterialNavigationDrawerTheme.Light">
        <item name="actionMenuTextColor">@color/white</item>
 </style>
```

in material drawer theme.xml (mostly irrelevant to this issue)

```
<style name="MaterialNavigationDrawerTheme.Light" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" >
        <item name="drawerType">@integer/DRAWERTYPE_ACCOUNTS</item>
        <item name="drawerColor">#fafafa</item>

    </style>
```

I understand that the theme `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar` has black text for the action bar but why isn't it changing when I include the line 
`<item name="actionMenuTextColor">@color/white</item>`

I have been trying to fix this for almost two days now tried so many things (eg [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22651646/how-to-change-actionbars-action-text-color-using-appcompat)) but nothing works

Any idea

Comment: If you use `...NoActionBar` theme, you provide your own `Toolbar` with its own `android:theme` attribute specified. The theme this attribute points to (often derived from `ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar` or `...Dark.ActionBar` has a `android:textColorPrimary` attribute which determines text color. Do not override this color in your main theme, it would change throughout your whole app.

Answer (score 0):

you could try this in styles.xml:

```
<style name="MyNavigationDrawerTheme" parent="MaterialNavigationDrawerTheme.Light">
    <item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:actionMenuTextAppearance">@style/TextAppearance.ActionMenu
    </item>
</style>
<style name="TextAppearance.ActionMenu">
     <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
</style>
```

ps: 
yeah ,sometimes it won't works only by android:actionMenuTextColor ,such as Galaxy S4

just add attr android:actionMenuTextAppearance

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using Toolbar, this is how you do it -

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@android:color/holo_red_dark</item>
    <item name="textColorPrimary">@android:color/holo_red_dark</item>
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>
```

Should work like a charm :)