# android actionbar overflow text color

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar

i cant find how to change my actionbar overflow text color... i'm able to set the title text color but not the overflow text color

themes.xml

```
<resources>
    <style name="MyAppTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyAppTheme.ActionBarStyle</item>
    </style>


 <style name="MyAppTheme.ActionBarStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:background">@color/blue</item>
        <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/MyAppTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle</item>
        <item name="android:displayOptions">showTitle</item>
  </style>

  <style name="MyAppTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

thx

Comment: Try this--> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24073004/change-the-title-text-color-in-the-android-actionbar-via-xml http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22651646/how-to-change-actionbars-action-text-color-using-appcompat

Comment: no... the problem is that i set the global TextView Textcolor to black. this also change the TextColor of the overflow and i have no idea how to overwrite this color again  <style name="TextViewAppTheme" parent="android:Widget.TextView">

        <item name="android:textColor">@color/black</item>
        <item name="android:typeface">normal</item>
    </style>

Comment: found the solution http://stackoverflow.com/a/28818974/4165710